# Can utilising Numpy functions inside the TensorFlow pipeline lead to memory leaks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

While training models in a loop using TensorFlow 2.14, the GPU RAM in use gradually increases until it reaches a maximum value at some iteration, at which point the process is killed.

So far, I've tried many solutions I've found (such as resetting the graph, training inside separate processes using Multiprocessing or closing CUDA with Numba). I ended up simply running my Python code in a loop from within bash.

While in theory this is some sort of solution, the issue leaves me confused. I have come across mentions that TensorFlow should not be used together with Numpy:

- [Memory leak in tf.py_function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/51839#issuecomment-924498386)
- [Call Tensorflow Model in a loop leaks memory](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/call-tensorflow-model-in-a-loop-leaks-memory/19792)

At the second link, I found such statement:

> Converting between TensorFlow tensors and Numpy arrays can be expensive and can lead to memory leaks if not managed properly.

Which would be bad news for me - in my project I have quite a lot of functions using Numpy, including tf.Tensor -> np.ndarray conversions and vice versa.

So, my question is **what is the underlying mechanism of the problem and how - if possible - to use Numpy inside the TensorFlow code without memory leaks** (and without discarding graph execution)?

*Edit:* Here are some Numpy functions I use between epochs:

- `np.zeros()`
- `np.array()`
- `flatten()`
- `np.unique()`
- `np.union1d()`
- `np.sum()`
- `np.logical_and()`
- `np.logical_not()`
- `np.mean()`

Moreover, I use numpy() in some places.

Comment: A small code example would be helpful. Where do you use which numpy functions? Inside a training loop?

Comment: @mhenning Including all code snippets containing Numpy functions would make the post a tapeworm. I edited the post and added the functions I use. And yes, I use them during training (to be specific - each time at the end of the epoch).

Comment: Without seeing how and where you use `numpy` function, I can just say, it's best practice to replace them with `TesorFlow` functions. If you use a GPU, the data has to be transferred back to CPU to get used with numpy, which is very inefficient. And for almost all the function you have listed, there are equivalent TF functions (look into the docs/google e.g. "tf mean"). In most cases it could be enough to replace "np.abc" with "tf.abc". For `np.union1d`, look into [`tf.sets.union`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sets/union)